# What is the difference between a helix and a vortex?

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition

I can't find anything useful elsewhere on the internet.  I've always thought that a vortex was just motion along a helix but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: A vortex is rotational like a helix but it's chaotic as well so you can't reverse time to find a previous state.

Comment: Okay.  So it follows the same geometric path but in random directions at random times?

Comment: It can't follow the same path as a helix because that's reversible. I can rewind time and show you what position on the helix it was in the past. It's more like a hurricane than a helix.